# How to use python to carry out descriptive analytics with large datasets over 10GB

Tags: python-3.x, large-data

I'm looking at a dataset which has over 10million rows and 100 fields of information. I'm trying to get the same information you would get if you used pandas.describe(), but in this case I can't read the whole file into a data frame.

Could anyone recommend a way to generate descriptive statistics with this very large datasets in python 3x?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: maybe look into dask?

Comment: @venky__ is there a describe function for dask? I loaded the data without any issues on dask.